# Fine-tuning BERT on SequenceClassification using Transformers framework

Tags: python, nlp, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

I am currently fine-tuning a BERT model on a sequence classification task. To do this, I am using the transformers framework. This requires a Batch input in a Trainer: https://huggingface.co/transformers/_modules/transformers/trainer.html

The way fine-tuning works, is described here: https://huggingface.co/transformers/custom_datasets.html
I think the Batch needs to look like I created it, but for some reason I keep getting errors. The picture shows a single item from the dataset.

If I add the labels as tensor, a part of the model that converts labels to tensors gives an error. But when I add the labels as list I get: Expected input batch_size (16) to match target batch_size (2016).
What is the correct way to give a Batch to the BERT model?

[image: What my dataSet object looks like]

Here is how I initialise the model:

```
training_args = TrainingArguments(
     output_dir='C:',          # output directory
     num_train_epochs=3,              # total number of training epochs
     per_device_train_batch_size=16,  # batch size per device during training
     per_device_eval_batch_size=64,   # batch size for evaluation
     warmup_steps=500,                # number of warmup steps for learning rate scheduler
     weight_decay=0.01,               # strength of weight decay
     logging_dir='C:',            # directory for storing logs
     logging_steps=10,
 )

tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
data_collator = DataCollatorForTokenClassification(tokenizer)
 
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,                           # the instantiated  Transformers model to be trained
    args=training_args,                    # training arguments, defined above
    data_collator=data_collator, #
    train_dataset=train_dataset,           # training dataset
    eval_dataset=test_dataset              # evaluation dataset
 )

trainer.train()
```

Comment: I've removed your [[tag:batch-file]] tag. There is no batch file code shown, and no batch file mentioned. Please hover over tags, and read their descriptions, before selecting only those which are pertinent to your question.

Comment: Whats the error?

Comment: I think your mistake is that you mix up sequence classification and token classification. For sequence classification, you provide only one label, while you provide #tokens labels for a token classification task.

Comment: @cronoik you are right. Thanks for figuring out that silly mistake. Now I can solve other errors while using BertForTokenClassification.. :)